# Issue with if/elif statement

Tags: python, if-statement

So, I created a simple program with an if and elif statement. However, no matter what I input, the code will read it as if I inputted A, which means no matter what it'll ask me to enter in a radians value. How could I go about fixing this?

```
import math

pi = math.pi


print("Do you wish to...")
print("(A)Convert radians to degrees.")
print("(B)Convert degrees to radians.")

choice = input(" ")

if choice == "A" or "a":
    rads = int(input("Enter in your radians value:\n"))
    degrees = rads * 180/pi
    print(rads, "radians = ", degrees," degrees")
elif choice == "B":
     degs = int(input("Enter in you degree value:\n"))
     radians = degs * pi/180
     print(degs, "degrees = ", radians," radians")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to be explicit with your comparisons.  The string "a" will evaluate to True (a non-zero length string) in your if statement.  So this line...

```
if choice == "A" or "a":
```

is saying if (choice == "A") or (True) which will always evaluate to True.  What you want is...

```
if choice == "A" or choice == "a":
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `choice == "A" or "a"` is equivalent to `(choice == "A") or bool("a")`.

And `bool("a")` is always `True`, so your `if` statement is unfalsifiable.

Instead, replace it with any of these options:

- `if choice.upper() == "A":`
- `if choice in ("A", "a"):`
- `if choice == "A" or choice == "a":`